# Index based dot product with numpy

Tags: numpy, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to optimize a transformation problem and let numpy do as much heavy-lifting as possible.

In my case I have a range of coordinate sets that each have to be dotted with corresponding indexed roll/pitch/yaw values.

Programatically it looks like this:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np 
   ...: from ds.tools.math import rotation_array 
   ...: from math import pi 
   ...:  
   ...: rpy1 = rotation_array(pi, 0.001232, 1.234243) 
   ...: rpy2 = rotation_array(pi/1, 1.325, 0.5674543)
In [2]: rpy1                                                                                                           
Out[2]: 
array([[ 3.30235500e-01,  9.43897768e-01, -1.23199969e-03],
       [ 9.43898485e-01, -3.30235750e-01,  1.22464587e-16],
       [-4.06850342e-04, -1.16288264e-03, -9.99999241e-01]])

In [3]: rpy2                                                                                                           
Out[3]: 
array([[ 2.05192356e-01,  1.30786082e-01, -9.69943863e-01],
       [ 5.37487075e-01, -8.43271987e-01,  2.97991829e-17],
       [-8.17926489e-01, -5.21332290e-01, -2.43328794e-01]])
   ...:  
   ...: a1 = np.array([[-9.64996132, -5.42488639, -3.08443], 
   ...:                [-8.08814188, -4.56431952, -3.01381]]) 
   ...:  
   ...: a2 = np.array([[-6.91346292, -3.91137259, -2.82621], 
   ...:                [-4.34534536, -2.34535546, -4.87692]])
```

Then I dot the coordinates in a1 with rpy1 and a2 with rpy2

```
In [4]: a1.dot(rpy1)                                                                                                   
Out[4]: 
array([[-8.30604694, -7.31349869,  3.09631641],
       [-6.97801968, -6.12357288,  3.0237723 ]])

In [5]: a2.dot(rpy2)                                                                                                   
Out[5]: 
array([[-1.20926993,  3.86756074,  7.3933692 ],
       [ 1.83673215,  3.95195774,  5.40143613]])
```

Instead of iterating over lists of a's and rpy's I want to do the whole thing in one operation. So I was hoping for that effect with the following code, so that each set of coordinates in a12 would be dotted with the corresponding indexed array from rpy_a.

But as it is clear, from the output I an getting more than I was hoping for:

```
In [6]: rpy_a = np.array([rpy1, rpy2]) 
   ...:  
   ...: a12 = np.array([a1, a2]) 

In [7]: a12.dot(rpy_a)                                                                                                 
Out[7]: 
array([[[[-8.30604694, -7.31349869,  3.09631641],
         [-2.37306761,  4.92058705, 10.1104514 ]],

        [[-6.97801968, -6.12357288,  3.0237723 ],
         [-1.6478126 ,  4.36234287,  8.57839034]]],


       [[[-5.9738597 , -5.23064061,  2.83472524],
         [-1.20926993,  3.86756074,  7.3933692 ]],

        [[-3.64678058, -3.32137028,  4.88226976],
         [ 1.83673215,  3.95195774,  5.40143613]]]])
```

What I need is:

```
array([[[-8.30604694, -7.31349869,  3.09631641],
        [-6.97801968, -6.12357288,  3.0237723 ]],

       [[-1.20926993,  3.86756074,  7.3933692 ],
        [ 1.83673215,  3.95195774,  5.40143613]]])
```

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

EDIT:
Runnable example:

```
import numpy as np

rpy1 = np.array([[ 3.30235500e-01,  9.43897768e-01, -1.23199969e-03],
                 [ 9.43898485e-01, -3.30235750e-01,  1.22464587e-16],
                 [-4.06850342e-04, -1.16288264e-03, -9.99999241e-01]])

rpy2 = np.array([[ 2.05192356e-01,  1.30786082e-01, -9.69943863e-01],
                 [ 5.37487075e-01, -8.43271987e-01,  2.97991829e-17],
                 [-8.17926489e-01, -5.21332290e-01, -2.43328794e-01]])

a1 = np.array([[-9.64996132, -5.42488639, -3.08443],
               [-8.08814188, -4.56431952, -3.01381]])

a2 = np.array([[-6.91346292, -3.91137259, -2.82621],
               [-4.34534536, -2.34535546, -4.87692]])

print(a1.dot(rpy1))
# array([[-8.30604694, -7.31349869,  3.09631641],
#        [-6.97801968, -6.12357288,  3.0237723 ]])
print(a2.dot(rpy2))
# array([[-1.20926993,  3.86756074,  7.3933692 ],
#        [ 1.83673215,  3.95195774,  5.40143613]])

rpy_a = np.array([rpy1, rpy2])
a12 = np.array([a1, a2])

print(a12.dot(rpy_a))
# Result:
# array([[[[-8.30604694, -7.31349869,  3.09631641],
#          [-2.37306761,  4.92058705, 10.1104514 ]],
#         [[-6.97801968, -6.12357288,  3.0237723 ],
#          [-1.6478126 ,  4.36234287,  8.57839034]]],
#        [[[-5.9738597 , -5.23064061,  2.83472524],
#          [-1.20926993,  3.86756074,  7.3933692 ]],
#         [[-3.64678058, -3.32137028,  4.88226976],
#          [ 1.83673215,  3.95195774,  5.40143613]]]])

# Need:
# array([[[-8.30604694, -7.31349869,  3.09631641],
#         [-6.97801968, -6.12357288,  3.0237723 ]],
#        [[-1.20926993,  3.86756074,  7.3933692 ],
#         [ 1.83673215,  3.95195774,  5.40143613]]])
```

Comment: Could you please show a sample of `rpy1` and `rpy2`? The module `ds` is not available (at least I can't import it and/or find it on pip).

Comment: Is `rpy` a 3x3, Euler rotation matrix?

Comment: I am adding rpy1 and rpy2 above - sorry

Comment: Thanks! You can also add it as executable code

Comment: Added runnable example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to treat an arbitrary number of arrays `rpy1, rpy2, ..., rpyn` and  `a1, a2, ..., an`, I suggest explicit first axis concatenation with explicit broadcasting, simply for the cause of *"explicit is better than implicit"*:

```
a12 = np.concatenate([_a[None, ...] for _a in (a1, a2)], axis=0)
rpy_a = np.concatenate([_a[None, ...] for _a in (rpy1, rpy2)], axis=0)
```

This is equal to:

```
a12 = np.array([a1, a2])
rpy_a = np.array([rpy1, rpy2])
```

`np.array` requires less code and is also faster than my explicit approach, but I just like defining the axis explicitly so that everyone reading the code can guess the resulting shape without executing it.

Whatever path you choose, the important part is the following:

```
np.einsum('jnk,jkm->jnm', a12, rpy_a)
# Out:
array([[[-8.30604694, -7.3134987 ,  3.09631641],
        [-6.97801969, -6.12357288,  3.0237723 ]],

       [[-1.20926993,  3.86756074,  7.3933692 ],
        [ 1.83673215,  3.95195774,  5.40143613]]])
```

Using the Einstein summation convention, you can define your `np.matmul` (equal to `np.dot` for 2D-arrays) to be executed along a specific axis.
In this case, we define the concatenation axis `j` (or first dim. or axis 0) to be the shared axis, along which the operation `'nk,km->nm'` (equal to [`np.matmul`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html#numpy.matmul), see the signature description in the `out` parameter) is performed.

It is also possible to simply use `np.matmul` (or the python operator `@`) for the same results:

```
np.matmul(a12, rpy_a)
a12 @ rpy_a
```

But again: For the general case, where the concatenation axis or shapes may change, the more explicit `np.einsum` is preferable. If you know that no changes will be made to shapes etc., `np.matmul` should be preferred (less code and faster).

Comment: `np.stack` is a duplicate of your initial `concatenate` code.

Comment: @hpaulj Yep, thanks for mentioning. That'd reduce the explicit part substantially. :)